# Using 3 or more modifier keys in AutoHotkey to replicate TouchCursor space trigger

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, script, autohotkey

I'm trying to replicate [TouchCursor](http://martin-stone.github.io/touchcursor/) keys using AutoHotkey, but I can't get it to work with multiple modifiers.

This is what I have so far (from https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=6525):

```
space & g::Send, {esc}
space & l::send, {right}
space & k::send, {up}
space & j::send, {down}
space & h::send, {left}
space & p::send, {backspace}
space & m::send, {delete}
space & u::send, {home}
space & o::send, {end}
space::
Send, {space}
return
```

The above script works fine to move the cursor around using 'h', 'j', 'k', and 'l', but it's ignoring `control` and `shift` keys.

For example, I was expecting to highlight letters using `space`+`shift`+`h` to highlight left similar to `space`+`shift`+`left arrow`.

I tried: `+space & h::send, {left}` and got the following error:

[image]

**EDIT**

This script will work with `control` and `shift`:

```
; Right, Shift+Right, Control+Right, Shift+Control+Right
space & l::
    if((GetKeyState("Shift", "P") and (GetKeyState("Control", "P")))) {
        send, +^{right}
    } else if(GetKeyState("Shift", "P")) {
        send, +{right}
    } else if(GetKeyState("Control", "P")) {
        send, ^{right}
    } else {
        send, {right}
    }
Return

; Up, Shift+Up, Control+Up, Shift+Control+Up
space & k::
    if((GetKeyState("Shift", "P") and (GetKeyState("Control", "P")))) {
        send, +^{up}
    } else if(GetKeyState("Shift", "P")) {
        send, +{up}
    } else if(GetKeyState("Control", "P")) {
        send, ^{up}
    } else {
        send, {up}
    }
Return

; Down, Shift+Down, Control+Down, Shift+Control+Down
space & j::
    if((GetKeyState("Shift", "P") and (GetKeyState("Control", "P")))) {
        send, +^{down}
    } else if(GetKeyState("Shift", "P")) {
        send, +{down}
    } else if(GetKeyState("Control", "P")) {
        send, ^{down}
    } else {
        send, {down}
    }
Return

; Left, Shift+Left, Control+Left, Shift+Control+Left
space & h::
    if((GetKeyState("Shift", "P") and (GetKeyState("Control", "P")))) {
        send, +^{left}
    } else if(GetKeyState("Shift", "P")) {
        send, +{left}
    } else if(GetKeyState("Control", "P")) {
        send, ^{left}
    } else {
        send, {left}
    }
Return

; Home, Shift+Home, Control+Home, Shift+Control+Home
space & u::
    if((GetKeyState("Shift", "P") and (GetKeyState("Control", "P")))) {
        send, +^{home}
    } else if(GetKeyState("Shift", "P")) {
        send, +{home}
    } else if(GetKeyState("Control", "P")) {
        send, ^{home}
    } else {
        send, {home}
    }
Return

; End, Shift+End, Control+End, Shift+Control+End
space & o::
    if((GetKeyState("Shift", "P") and (GetKeyState("Control", "P")))) {
        send, +^{end}
    } else if(GetKeyState("Shift", "P")) {
        send, +{end}
    } else if(GetKeyState("Control", "P")) {
        send, ^{end}
    } else {
        send, {end}
    }
Return

; Backspace, Shift+Backspace
space & p::
    if(GetKeyState("Control", "P")) {
        send, ^{backspace}
    } else {
        send, {backspace}
    }
Return

; Simple modifiers
space & g::Send, {esc} 
space & m::send, {delete}

; Allow space bar to go through if pressed without holding
space::
Send, {space}
return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use an [if statement](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfExpression.htm) with the [GetKeyState](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GetKeyState.htm) function to capture the extra modifiers. Specifically to find the `P` (Physical state) of the `shift` modifier.

For example, the `space & h` combination:

```
space & h::
    if(GetKeyState("Shift", "P")) {
        send, +{left}
    } else {
        send, {left}
    }
Return
```

I suspect you will probably go a step further and want to implement the `ctrl` modifier as well. You would need to expand upon the if statement and be careful of the way the if statement executes.

```
space & h::
    if((GetKeyState("Shift", "P") and (GetKeyState("Control", "P")))) {
        send, +^{left}
    } else if(GetKeyState("Shift", "P")) {
        send, +{left}
    } else if(GetKeyState("Control", "P")) {
        send, ^{left}
    } else {
        send, {left}
    }
Return
```

You need to check the key states of `Shift` and `Control` first, and then the individual modifiers otherwise it would exit too early and only execute one of the modifiers.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I need. I will post the complete script to the question.

Comment: You can also use [#If directives](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm) to create context-sensitive hotkeys (Hotkey variants with #If criteria always have precedence).